# strcat not flushing

Tags: c++, arduino, strcat

I have this code in arduino

```
void function(int x){
    char* response="GET /postTEST.php?first=";

    char strx[2] = {0};
    int num = x;
    sprintf(strx, "%d", num); 

    original=response;
    strcat(response,strx);
    Serial.println(response);
    //memset(response,'\0',80);
}
```

Basically, it is to join an integer to my post string. Unfortunately, it somehow grows and becomes 
    GET /postTEST.php?first=0
    GET /postTEST.php?first=01
    GET /postTEST.php?first=012
as i increase i.

How come?

Comment: Is the passed integer a single digit? That's all you allocate space for with `strx[2]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can not modify a string literal. String literals are constant.

You have to declare it as an array with enough space to add the number.

You also do some unnecessary steps, I suggest something like this:

```
void function(int x)
{
    char response[64];

    sprintf(response, "GET /postTEST.php?first=%d", x);

    Serial.println(response);
}
```